# How to rotate proxy with Python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am experimenting with Python and am trying to build simple Google Scraper. To that, I try to implement proxies but I don't have enough knowledge.

So far my code looks like this:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import warnings
from googlesearch import search
from itertools import cycle

warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", module='bs4')

proxies = {
'http:myproxies_url'

}
proxy_pool = cycle(proxies)
proxy = next(proxy_pool)

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:69.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/69.0',
'Accept': '*/*',
'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
'Connection': 'keep-alive'}

def searchBing(query, num):

    urls = []

    for j in search(query, tld="co.in", num=10, stop=10, pause=3): 
            proxies = {
                "http": proxy,
                "https":proxy
            }
            urls.append(j) 


    return urls[:num]

def extractText(url):
    page = requests.get(url,proxies=proxies)
    soup = bs(page.text, 'html.parser')
    return soup.get_text()
```

This is an error form the console:

```
no_proxy = proxies.get('no_proxy') if proxies is not None else None
AttributeError: 'set' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Comment: Please update the code with the line that throws the error, but from what I can see is that your `proxies` is not a `dict` but a `set`, hence the issue.

Answer (score 0):

`proxies` is a [set](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset),

```
proxies = {
   'http:myproxies_url'
}
```

the error suggests to me that the it isn't being set to the dictionary via the `searchBing` function. I'd recommend updating your variable names so that there ins't a chance for this to happen.

---